# Создание фоновых повторяющихся задач во flask

Tags: python, flask, celery

Необходимо сотворить управление (запускать и выключать) повторяющиеся фоновые задачи/таски.
пример: есть на сайте кнопка "включить уведомление о новостях", при активации ее, пользователю каждый час/день/5 минут приходят уведомления. При выключении ее перестали приходить и тд.

Фоновые задачи можно реализовать с помощью celery, но в него можно отправить задание единожды: выполнилось и все. Так же в нем есть периодичные задачи, но их необходимо создавать перед запуском приложения, и менять на лету нет возможности.

Может есть какие то другие решения.